# Replace for loop with apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I'm trying to replace the commented out for loop below with apply and a lambda function but I'm getting the error below.  My python is rusty, so any tips are greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-b29bfb93595e>", line 11
if (dataDF < dataDF.shift()) & (dataDF.shift(periods=1) < dataDF.shift(periods=2)):
                                                                                  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Code:

```
def get_recession_end():
    dataDF = pd.ExcelFile('gdplev.xls').parse(skiprows=7)[['Unnamed: 4',     'Unnamed: 5']].loc[246:]
    dataDF.columns = ['Quarter','dataDF']
    dataDF['dataDF'] = pd.to_numeric(dataDF['dataDF'])

    #quarters = []
    #for i in range(len(dataDF) - 2):
        #if (dataDF.iloc[i][1] < dataDF.iloc[i+1][1]) & (dataDF.iloc[i+1][1] <     dataDF.iloc[i+2][1]):
            #quarters.append(dataDF.iloc[i+2][0])
    #return quarters[0]

    quarters = dataDF.apply(lambda x: quarters = []
                                      if (dataDF < dataDF.shift()) &     (dataDF.shift(periods=1) < dataDF.shift(periods=2)):
                                          quarters.append(dataDF.shift(2)[0]))
    return quarters[0]

get_recession_end()
```

Update New Version:

Code:

```
def get_recession_end():
def get_recession_end():
    dataDF = pd.ExcelFile('gdplev.xls').parse(skiprows=7)[['Unnamed: 4', 
'Unnamed: 5']].loc[246:]#skiprows=17,skip_footer=(38))
    dataDF.columns = ['Quarter','dataDF']
    dataDF['dataDF'] = pd.to_numeric(dataDF['dataDF'])
   #quarters = []
    #for i in range(len(dataDF) - 2):
        #if (dataDF.iloc[i][1] < dataDF.iloc[i+1][1]) & (dataDF.iloc[i+1][1] 
< dataDF.iloc[i+2][1]):
            #quarters.append(dataDF.iloc[i+2][0])
    #return quarters[0]
    def do_the_foo(x):
        quarters = []
        if (dataDF < dataDF.shift()) & (dataDF.shift(periods=1) < 
dataDF.shift(periods=2)):
            quarters.append(dataDF.shift(2)[0])
        return quarters

    quarters = dataDF.loc[:(len(dataDF) - 2)].apply(do_the_foo)
    return quarters[0]


get_recession_end()
```

New Error:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1944             try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-53e0a21f9faa> in <module>()
     18 
 19 
---> 20 get_recession_end()

<ipython-input-10-53e0a21f9faa> in get_recession_end()
     15 
     16     quarters = dataDF.loc[:-(len(dataDF) - 2)].apply(do_the_foo)
---> 17     return quarters[0]
     18 
     19 

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1996         else:
-> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1998 
   1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
_getitem_column(self, key)
   2002         # get column
   2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2005 
   2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
_get_item_cache(self, item)
   1348         res = cache.get(item)
   1349         if res is None:
-> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
   1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1352             cache[item] = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self,
```

item, fastpath)
       3288 
       3289             if not isnull(item):
    -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
       3291             else:
       3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))
    [isnull(self.items)]

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
-> 1947                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

[lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) are restricted to a single expression. You've tried to use multiple statements. lambda expressions are just a convenient way to inline a small function and can always be replaced by a regular funtion. Since the lambda references a variable in the outer function scope, the replacement function should also be defined in that scope.

The result doesn't look any better than the original you are trying to replace. So, I think the real answer is that you can't use a lambda this way.

```
def get_recession_end():
    dataDF = pd.ExcelFile('gdplev.xls').parse(skiprows=7)[['Unnamed: 4',     'Unnamed: 5']].loc[246:]
    dataDF.columns = ['Quarter','dataDF']
    dataDF['dataDF'] = pd.to_numeric(dataDF['dataDF'])

    #quarters = []
    #for i in range(len(dataDF) - 2):
        #if (dataDF.iloc[i][1] < dataDF.iloc[i+1][1]) & (dataDF.iloc[i+1][1] <     dataDF.iloc[i+2][1]):
            #quarters.append(dataDF.iloc[i+2][0])
    #return quarters[0]

    def do_the_foo(x):
        quarters = []
        if (dataDF < dataDF.shift()) & (dataDF.shift(periods=1) < dataDF.shift(periods=2)):
            quarters.append(dataDF.shift(2)[0])
        return quarters

    quarters = dataDF.apply(do_the_foo)

get_recession_end()
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I tried adding your suggestion.  I have the new code above in the "Updated New Version", and I'm getting a new set of errors.  I more familiar with writing r code.  So I prefer apply to writing loops, that's why I'm trying to do this with apply.  I'm still getting the hang of this in python, so thank you very much for the help.  Do the errors make sense to you, can you suggest how to fix the code?